# Use storyboard from Framework in Xcode 6 iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am trying to build a framework that has a storyboard and a bunch of images in an assets catalogue. The image assets are accessed in code and from the storyboard. How do I allow another project to include the framework and access the storyboard/assets from the framework?

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has gotten easier with the latest version of XCode.

The old way still works and I don't think you can find a better example than the one presented by Ray's team.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

This is a long tutorial and needs to be followed closely but it does work and is an excellent solution.